# How to suppress Warning Type: Not LLVM Warning?

Tags: android, build

How to suppress below Warning Type: Not LLVM Warning in Android ?

```
- Line Number: 11
- Warning Message: tag "sysui_heads_up_escalation" (36003) duplicated in frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/EventLogTags.logtags:11
- Warning Type: Not LLVM Warning
```